# Developing Apache camel application & run on Karaf

Tags: apache-camel, integration

I am developing an integration application and planned to use apache camel. After doing initial study I found that there are various ways to develop apache camel application(Indeed, this is a library and can be associated with any java application) like spring boot, spring and plain java & routes can be defined in DSL or xml file.

I have created one application using spring libraries and working fine on my local eclipse when I run it as a java program.

Now,as I want to run same in osgi container, created a bundle jar file by mvn install (after chaning packaging option and added felix plugin in pom file) and I was able to update the same in Jboss Fuse(Karaf) by osgi:install command. However, it just installed but did not work and I guess the osgi container can not create CamelContext by its own untill application instruct it (as my application was created as spring application).

I am afraid about the steps I mentioned is very high level and probably not enough to create apache camel application. I also found some fabric8 and kubernates concepts to create apache camel application but not able to grasp which and how to use it. there are various links available but mostly are outdated or unclear.

Can anyone please share the general guideline to create an camel application which can run on osgi container in high availability.

Update- 
Yesterday, I learned that the kubernate/openshift is the runtime platform (means we can run the apache camel as a standalone or on kubernate/openshift platform) and runtime environment could be spring boot, karaf (osgi container).

Now, I have created one camel application with runtime platform standalone and runtime envrironment Karaf.this application runs good when I run in IDE. however, wehen  I deploy it to Karaf it does not do its job. Deployed using following commands.

install -s mvn:com.mycompany/camel-java-cbr/1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
start bundleID

Comment: Hi, I suggest you take a look at the [JBoss Fuse documentation](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_jboss_fuse/6.3/html/deploying_into_apache_karaf/injection#DeployCamel-Frameworks). You _can_ use spring but it is recommended that you use blueprint when developing Camel applications that will be run in an OSGi-container such as Karaf.

Comment: Hi NoMad, thanks. it's working now after using blueprint project. I am wondering If I use spring boot or oSGI Container to run the apache project. what are the disadvantage running in spring boot runtime envrionment.