# Why hawtio/OSGi/Jboss Fuse doesn't recognize camel routes?

Tags: java, apache-camel, jbossfuse, hawtio

I've tried to publish https://code.google.com/archive/p/apache-camel-mashup/downloads app to my JBoss Fuse using Red Hat JBoss Development Studio but Camel routes are not determined.

I see that it must work because camel context is defined in META-INF/Spring and pom.xml seems to be ok.

Could you tell me what should I do to force the app to work properly? The status of the app is "Active" but I can't see THE routes in hawtio or via camel-routes or in JMX.

The camlel-context is

```
<camelContext xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
    <package>de.fhb.morgenthal</package>
</camelContext>
```

Comment: Please add your configs (Spring, Camel) to the question.

Comment: Please, take a look at the documentation posted in my comment for a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50349735/developing-apache-camel-application-run-on-karaf?noredirect=1#comment87822697_50349735). Like I said there: while you _can_ use Spring it is recommended that you instead use blueprint when developing Camel applications to be published in an OSGi-container.

Comment: Which version of JBoss Fuse are you using?  The linked apache-camel-mashup project looks very old, and it may be well likely that it's not compatible with the latest JBoss Fuse.